# str_pad() expects parameter 1 to be string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a below php code where I am using `str_pad` but whenever I run this code I am getting an error as -

```
            function buildCurrentMonth($month)
            {
                # array will hold months
                $months = [
                    str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
                    str_pad(($month + 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
                ];
             .....
            }

          <?php echo buildCurrentMonth(date('n')); ?>
```

Error is -

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: str_pad() expects parameter 1 to be string, int given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/index.php:59 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/index.php(59): str_pad(10, 2, '0', 0) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/index.php(144): buildCurrentMonth('9') #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/index.php on line 59
```

I checked the manual and it looks good to me but I am not sure what's wrong here?

Looks like it throws error on second `str_pad` line which is below and month is passed as 9 to the above method -

```
str_pad(($month + 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: What is in `$month`? You're doing `$month +1` which generates a number.

Comment: I am calling above method as `<?php echo buildCurrentMonth(date('n')); ?>` which is the current month.

Comment: The error is quite explicit. If you are not fluent in English there is a lot of online translators to help you.

Comment: `date('n')` returns a number, not a string.

Comment: first param get a string and not a number, maybe you should cast it to string

Comment: Why do you need to pad the numbers with 0's anyway? That can be done when outputting the date in a specific format.

Comment: Whatever you want to do, you are doing it wrong. Use the class [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime) handle times and dates and [`DateTime.format('m')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to get the representation of the month on two digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`str_pad()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) expects a string as its first argument but `$month + 1` is a number. But this is not the right way to work with dates.

Use the class [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime) and its relatives to handle times and dates and [`DateTime.format('m')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to get the representation of the month on two digits.

```php
function buildMonth(DateTime $date)
{
  # array will hold months
  $months = [
    $date->format('m'),                // the month of $date
    (clone $date)->add(new DateInterval('P1M'))->format('m'),    // add one month
  ];
  // .....

  return $months;
}

print_r(buildMonth(new DateTime('2020-09-22 18:17:31 +0300')));

// Output
Array
(
    [0] => 09
    [1] => 10
)
```

Check it out: https://3v4l.org/2QHC9

**Remark:**

The function uses `clone` to avoid modifying the object passed as argument. An alternative (and better) way is to use [`DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) instead of `DateTime`. As `DateTimeImmutable`, `$date` doesn't need to be cloned any more. The methods of class `DateTimeImmutable` that are not read only do not change the object; they return a new object instead. The code is a bit simpler and much safer this way:

```php
function buildMonth(DateTimeImmutable $date)
{
  # array will hold months
  $months = [
    $date->format('m'),                // the month of $date
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'))->format('m'),    // add one month
  ];
  // .....

  return $months;
}

print_r(buildMonth(new DateTimeImmutable('2020-09-22 18:17:31 +0300')));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation [belew](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) of *str_pad*, it get a string at the first parametre.
In your code you use `($month + 1)` as a first param, may be you should cast it with `strval($month + 1)`